# Why doesn't my LocalStorage data load the first time sometimes but if I refresh it always loads in?

Tags: jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I'm building a mobile app using jQuery Mobile, testing on iOS. It's a simple checklist app (at least for now) which uses HTML5 `LocalStorage` to save `checkbox` data as to which items are completed. I had some trouble with this at first but I've gotten it working mostly.

It works most of the time but sometimes the page just loads normally except none of the checkbox data is there. Everything is false. If you refresh the page though, it's back to normal with the data filled in.

Is there any reason why the `LocalStorage` wouldn't work on first load but then work on refresh? Yet, sometimes it works perfectly the first load.

My test site is here:
http://gojustin.net/acchecklist/

More often than not it seems to break on the Bugs page. (only Fish and Bugs are operational at the moment, don't bother with Paintings and Fossils)

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap implements its own version of HTML5 local storage on iOS since native support was removed from `UIWebView`.

To be sure local storage works, wait for the `deviceready` event before accessing it.

Functionality is intermittent because of the race condition between PhoneGap initializing, and the attempt to use `localStorage`. Reloading works because it has loaded by the second time through.

Comment: This is a good point but at the moment I'm testing in the browser only before PhoneGap is even introduced and the problem is still there.

Comment: @FearMyWrench Edited question to reflect that requirement

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a caching issue: use the following to disable caching, then clear your browser cache, and then reload the page to see if your problem is fixed.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to change anything. :(